# Force nginx to redirect one domain to another while keeping URL structure?

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-redirect

I am looking for a way to redirect exampledomain.com to exampledomain2.com, while also maintaining the URL structure. For example:

http://exampledomain.com/forum/post1.php

would redirect to

http://exampledomain2.com/forum/post1.php

Does anyone have a simple solution to this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Should be straightforward:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.old-name.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.new-name.com$request_uri;
}
```

Please see this [blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) for more info.